# python pycasso scramble rectangular tiles

Tags: python, canvas, slice, rectangles, pycassa

I am using pycasso to scramble an image and was wondering does anybody know haw to input rectangles instead of squares for the slice_size

```
from pycasso import Canvas
img = 'input.jpeg'
slice_size = 200
seed = 'seed'
pycasso = Canvas(img, slice_size, seed)
pycasso.export(mode='scramble', path='image_output.png')
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be an option with the current implementation:
https://github.com/catsital/pycasso/blob/27f014d7a57cde03804943ecab948d409cd70715/pycasso/unscramble.py#L13-L20

```
class Canvas:
    def __init__(self, img, slice_size, seed=None):
        self.img = Image.open(img)
        self.slice_size = abs(slice_size)
        self.seed = seed
        self.canvas = Image.new(mode="RGBA",
                                size=(self.img_width, self.img_height),
                                color=(255,255,255))
```

In the constructor for the `class Canvas` we have the variable `slice_size` and that will be used for both vertical and horizontal slices ... that is all we have at the moment.

---

However it should not be too difficult to modify that code to allow two parameters in the constructor, the variable `slice_size` it's just used in a few places:
https://github.com/catsital/pycasso/search?q=slice_size
Just look at each and determine if is vertical or horizontal slices and replace accordingly...

You can make the change yourself and submit a Pull Request (PR) or just open a new issue:
https://github.com/catsital/pycasso/issues/new
Explain in detail why you need this and the owner should see the benefits